# php how to get a string in a specific place

Tags: php, regex

I have this string

> http://myipaddress:myport/mycompanyname/morethings?lovelyparameter

I want to take the word `mycompanyname`

any help?

I tried this:

```
$indexName = preg_match("http://p+:p+/","http://myipaddress:myport/mycompanyname/morethings?lovelyparameter" );
```

but I got this error:

```
preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

Comment: Is `mycompanyname` just after `:myport/` ?

Comment: Is this a fixed position in some strings, such as third parameter or something? You can tokenize the string using the / as the separator.

Comment: @noob it is always after the port, but also it is followed by othertings as you see inthe example there is a "morethings" followed by my company

Comment: @StevenScott yes it is fixed, my company name is always after the port.

Comment: Then capture the first group from this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/gS2mB3/1).

Comment: [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) might be helpful in some way...(just note that you can't use it with string `myport` - I know it's just an example, but it seems that it HAS to be a number)

Comment: @noob did you mean use that regular expression with `preg_match` ?

Comment: @user2059935: Yes, and use the first group using `\1` or `$1` whatever is supported in `php`. Am not a php programmer sorry !

Comment: The strtok should work for you as it parses to an array then you can take the 3rd element for the domain name.

Comment: Here's the reason for your current error, http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php. What are you trying to do with `p+`?

Comment: You have to wrap regex pattern into delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character. Also, your `p+:p+` syntax is not correct (it will match something like 'ppp:ppp', literally). Also, you have to define a group enclosing-it by parenthesis to catch desired subpattern. See [Pattern syntax in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you don't want the preg functions, and something else from the url, you can use [**parse_url()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). It would look like this:

```
$a = 'http://myipaddress:8080/mycompanyname/morethings?lovelyparameter';
$b = parse_url($a);
print_r($b);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => myipaddress
    [port] => 8080
    [path] => /mycompanyname/morethings
    [query] => lovelyparameter
)
```

That way, just use something like:

```
$path = $b['path'];
$foo = explode('/', $path)[1];
echo $foo;
```

Output:

> mycompanyname

---

**Side notes:**

- This code won't check for malformed url, so you should do some check of your own.
- If you test the url with a port number as string (as you have in the question), it won't work.

---

It could be done in one line:

```
$url = 'http://myipaddress:8080/mycompanyname/morethings?lovelyparameter';
echo explode('/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH))[1];
```

Output:

> mycompanyname

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode as

```
$abc = 'http://myipaddress:myport/mycompanyname/morethings?lovelyparameter';

$a = explode('/', $abc);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($a[3]);
echo '</pre>';
```

The explode breaks the strings into parts and returns an array of strings so you can check in array too for mycompanyname..

Answer (score 1):

For the records, you were missing appropriate delimiters. [A regex solution would be](https://regex101.com/r/cJ9uK2/1):

```
https?://.+?/(?P<company>[^/]+)/
```

In `PHP` this would be:

```
$regex = '~https?://.+?/(?P<company>[^/]+)/~';
$url = 'http://myipaddress:8080/mycompanyname/morethings?lovelyparameter';
preg_match($regex, $url, $match);
echo $match["company"];
// mycompanyname
```